# Multi users wth multi data set login scenairon for jmeter not working

Tags: http, while-loop, jmeter, performance-testing

I need to test multi users login scenario with different data set on single operation. let say For each 10 user I wants to open different 10 documents at a time and do some operations on it. I created below plan to test this case.

```
TestPlan 
Thread Group
    While controller
        CSVLoginUserDataConfig
        LoginRequestRecordingController
            HTTPLoginRequset
        DocumentOperationRecordingController
            While Controlder
                DocIDCSVDataList
                HttpSaveRequest
```

My problem is I get 10 users login successfully but for DocuemntOperation all DocIDs pass to single thread(users) so Only single user is doing operation at a time. I wants to achieve 10 users get 10 different DocIds and perform operation on it simultaneously.

Where I need to change my test plan or settings of any sampler\config to achieve my scenario?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not removing `While Controller` under `DocumentOperationRecordingController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `While Controller` under `DocumentOperationRecordingController`

Currently every user/thread is looping and using the 10 different DocIds instead of using DocId for each user

Comment: After removing While Controller now for 10 users with 100 documentID scenario not working. It fetch first 10 docid and stop the execution. I have below settings for Thread Group: No Of Thread: 10 Loop Count : 1 Ramp-up Period: 2

Comment: @dingo can you open a new question with CSV Data Config